# twig array of objects

Tags: arrays, object, symfony, methods, twig

I'm working on a symfony2 project.

I send from my controller to twig, an array of arrays of objects.
My array is nicely set, and got the values I want.

But when I try to access to these datas on twig, I can't...
My twig looks like `{{ myarray.1.0.getFichier() }}`

But, twig didn't call `getFichier` method of `myarray.1.0`.

Here is what twig responses to me : `Item "getFichier" for "Array" does not exist in CDUserBundle:Prof:edit_session.html.twig at line 74`

Edit : 
dump(myarray.1.0) shows nothing, dump(myarray) shows nothing.
But dump() show a blank page...

Edit² :
 Here is my controller

```
return $this->render('CDUserBundle:Prof:edit_session.html.twig', array(
            'erreur' => $erreur,'message' => $message,
            'title' => 'C# | Editer session',
            'description' => 'keywords description',
            'sessionInfo' => $sessionInfo,
            'sessionFull' => $sessionFull,
            'documents' => $documents,
            'videos' => $videos,
            'a' => 'showForm',
            'vidName' => $videos[0]->getName(),
            'vidDMCId'=>$videos[0]->getDMCId(),
            'session' => $form->createView(),
            'partPath' => $documents[0]->getFichier()
        ));
```

My Array is either $documents either $videos
Here is when I create arrays

```
  $videos=array();
    if($sessionFull[0]['sess_vid_id']!=NULL) {
        if($em->getRepository('CD\ConfigBundle\Entity\Video')->findOneById($sessionFull[0]['sess_vid_id']))
            array_push($videos,$em->getRepository('CD\ConfigBundle\Entity\Video')->findOneById($sessionFull[0]['sess_vid_id']));
        else
            array_push($videos,new Video());
        }
    else
        array_push($videos,new Video());
    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
        if($sessionFull[$i]['coursVidId']!=NULL) {
            $vids=array();
            $vidsId=explode(',',$sessionFull[$i]['coursVidId']);
            foreach($vidsId as $vidId) {
                if($em->getRepository('CD\ConfigBundle\Entity\Video')->findOneById($vidId))
                    array_push($vids,$em->getRepository('CD\ConfigBundle\Entity\Video')->findOneById($vidId));
                else
                    array_push($vids,new Video());
            }
            array_push($videos,$vids);
        }
        else
            array_push($videos,array(new Video()));
    }

    $documents=array();
    if($sessionFull[0]['sess_doc_id']!=NULL) {
        if($em->getRepository('CD\ConfigBundle\Entity\Document')->findOneById($sessionFull[0]['sess_doc_id']))
            array_push($documents,$em->getRepository('CD\ConfigBundle\Entity\Document')->findOneById($sessionFull[0]['sess_doc_id']));
        else
            array_push(new Document());
    }
    else
        array_push($documents,new Document());
    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
        if($sessionFull[$i]['coursDocId']!=NULL) {
            $docs=array();
            $docsId=explode(',',$sessionFull[$i]['coursDocId']);
            foreach($docsId as $docId) {
                if($em->getRepository('CD\ConfigBundle\Entity\Document')->findOneById($docId))
                    array_push($docs,$em->getRepository('CD\ConfigBundle\Entity\Document')->findOneById($docId));
                else
                    array_push($docs,new Document());
            }
            array_push($documents,$docs);
        }
        else
            array_push($documents,array(new Document()));
    }
```

Comment: If you use the [`dump`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) function on `myarray.1.0` what do you get? Is your method `public`?

Comment: Dump shows nothing. My method come from Doctrine Entity, so yes I think. Maybe my object have been empty set ( new Document() )

Comment: What if you use `{{ dump(myarray) }}` then? Can you post the result in your question?

Comment: Post your Twig template pls.

Comment: As `dump(myarray)` shows nothing, can you show us the controller code? (or at least the part where you create and the on where you send the `myarray` object to the view)

Comment: My array work on my controller. I use several times `$documents[1][0]`
I show you on edit!

Comment: If `$documents[1][0]` works and you pass `'documents' => $documents` to your view. Then how about using `{{ documents.1.0.getFichier() }}` in your twig template? Where does `myarray` come from in your view?

Comment: my array was for simplify my problem. I don't have my array, error come from $documents. And structur of $documents and $videos are similars.

Comment: And you can access `videos` in your twig template? If yes then I think the problem is definitely coming from the way you initialize your `$documents` variable.

Comment: what about using `{{ document[1][0].fichier }}` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use {{ myarray.1.0.Fichier }} directly